# Show Skype for Business presecence

Tags: javascript, c#, skype, skype-for-business

We are looking to show an icon in a web application that depicts a users current presence in Skype For Business.  Every user will have the Skype for Business application installed and running.

We have looked at https://ucwa.skype.com/websdk however even the interactive Web SDK appears to need some prerequisites for your domain to be white listed etc before you can even use that.

Has anyone ever been able to implement this WebSDK or found another simple way to show presence?